# Why can't I jump to the help files I've written?

Tags: neovim, help-system

I am writing neovim help documentation for a plugin I am developing that reads as follows.

project.txt

```
*project* description

...

=================================================================================
CONTENT                                                    *project*

    1. Introduction                                        |project-introduction|
    2. Quickstart                                          |project-quickstart|
    3. Commands                                            |project-commands|
    4. Configuraion                                        |project-configuration|

=================================================================================
 1. INTRODUCTION                                            *project-introduction*

...

=================================================================================
 2. QUICKSTART                                              *project-quickstart*

...

=================================================================================
 3. COMMANDS                                                *project-commands*

...

=================================================================================
 4. CONFIGURAION                                            *project-configuration*

...
```

tags

```
project project.txt /*project*
project-introduction    project.txt /*project-introduction*
project-quickstart  project.txt /*project-quickstart*
project-commands    project.txt /*project-commands*
project-configuration   project.txt /*project-configuration*
```

I found that I can only jump to `project`, `project-commands` and `project-configuration`, but not to `project-introduction` and `project-quickstart`.

I tried `cat` to print ANSI characters:

```bash
$ cat -A doc/tags
project^Iproject.txt^I/*project*$
project-introduction^Iproject.txt^I/*project-introduction*$
project-quickstart^Iproject.txt^I/*project-quickstart*$
project-commands^Iproject.txt^I/*project-commands*$
project-configuration^Iproject.txt^I/*project-configuration*$
```

I'm using `<TAB>` correctly, without converting it to a space.

But I really don't understand why there is a problem that some titles cannot be jumped.

============================== Replenish ==========================

When neovim jumps to the help document, the error message given is as follows:

```
:help project-introduction
E426: tag not found: project-introducion@en
```

neovim version: 0.8.2

Comment: did you run `:helptags`

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I tried `:tag project-commands` and it redirected successfully, but `:tag project-introduction` still doesn’t work.

Comment: sorry, I don't follow. How did you create the tags file? Did you not run `:helptags` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved: the reason is in the tags file, but it is not a grammatical error. Let me show the correct ANSI characters of the tags file directly:

```
project^Iproject.txt^I/*project*$
project-introduction^Iproject.txt^I/*project-introduction*$
project-quickstart^Iproject.txt^I/*project-quickstart*$
project-commands^Iproject.txt^I/*project-commands*$
project-configuration^Iproject.txt^I/*project-configuration*$
$
```

The key is at the end of the file, there must be two newlines.

If there is only one newline character at the end of the file, only the first and last two tags are valid, and other tags are invalid.

I don't know the reason for the time being. In addition, I found that the help documents in the plug-ins developed by others do not have two newlines at the end of the file, but their documents can be used normally.

---

I have been manually writing tags before, according to @Christian Brabandt's tip, (neo)vim has a `:helptags <dir>` command to automatically generate tags files.

Comment: How did you create the tags file? You should run `:helptags` to have vim create it properly

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Thanks for the reminder, I always thought you were telling me to run `:help tags` to see the manual.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I have been manually writing the tags file before, I used `cat -A tags` to compare, the tags file automatically generated by `:helptags` is almost the same as the tags file I wrote manually, do you know the reason?

Comment: I don't know why. I would always have vim generate the tags file. That has always worked for me and the helpfiles I have written

Comment: Hi @aszswaz if this solution solves your problem maybe could you accept your answer to make the question rest. You can do that using the v green button next to the arrow voting buttons. You can accept your own answers two days after you post it.